# Is that a valid way to prove indifferentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Given the following exercise:

> Let  $  f(x, y) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{x^3}{x^2 + y^2},  & \text{if $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$} \\
> 0, & \text{if (x, y) = (0, 0)}  \\
> \end{cases}$
>
> Check whether $f(x, y)$ differentiable at $(0, 0)$.

My answer:

> In order for $f$ to be differentiable at $(0,0)$ the following must be true:
>
> $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{f(x, y) - xf'_x(0,0) - yf'_y(0, 0) - f(0, 0)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0$$
>
> (Note: in the previous section I found that $f'_x(0, 0) = 1$ and $f'_y(0, 0) = 0$).
>
> $\color{red}{\text{Move to polar coordinates}}$:
>
> $$x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta, x^2 + y^2 = r^2.$$
>   Then: $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \bigg(\frac{x^3}{x^2 + y^2} - x - 0\bigg) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \lim_{r \to 0} \bigg(\frac{r^3\cos^3\theta}{r^2} - r\cos\theta\bigg)\cdot\frac{1}{r} \\= \lim_{r\to0}\cos^3\theta-\cos\theta \ne 0$$.

Is my solution right? thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Yup, that's a valid way to show it.